# What is the prefered way to query multiple tables in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a pretty straight forward link table representing modules and tutors

```
    final String table = "module_tutor";
    final String[] columns = {"module_id"};
    final String where = "tutor_id = ?";
    final String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(tutorID)};
    final String groupBy = null;
    final String having = null;
    final String orderBy = "module_id";

    Cursor c = getDbAdapter().selectRecordsFromDB(table, columns, where, whereArgs,  groupBy, having, orderBy);
```

This cursor then contains all the module_id records where this particular tutor is the the tutor, what I want is to get hold of all the module details which are stored in a different table.

What is the best way to retrieve these, do I use values from the cursor to construct a really long raw sql query in a loop, appending the module_id while the cursor has a next record, or should I abandon using a cursor and write an SQL Query along the lines of

```
SELECT module_title, module_credit, module_xyz
FROM modules
WHERE module_id IN
    (
     SELECT module_id
     FROM module_tutor
     WHERE tutor_id = ?
    )
```

if the latter is preferable, although I'd rather avoid this as my table structure could at this point change and the first solution is easier to manage how do I go about implementing  this in SQLite - Once I have the database working internally for my application I intend to expose it via a Content Provider so the cursor solution again seems preferable as I think its a little bit closer to how I'll finally end up using the database within my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a nested select, just join the two tables:

```
select module_title, module_credit from modules m, module_tutor mt 
where mt.module_id=m.id and mt.tutori_id=?
```

If you have a ContentProvider, you don't have to expose the actual table structure, etc., so you should be relatively free to make changes to the underlying database. Use what ever is easier and most efficient.

Comment: My understanding was a content provider returned a cursor so I am looking to have the code implementing a cursor so I can just swap out where the cursor is assigned once I've implemented the Content Provider.

Comment: Yes, but the Cursor you return doesn't have to be the same one you get from the underlying database. That is the most straightforward and usual way to implement it though.